# How to terminate a piped command?

Tags: linux, pipe, kill

Let's say there is a simple script named `action.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n 'a' | nc a.b.c.d p
```

*action.sh* here puts an `a` character to `a.b.c.d` address.

However, `nc` can hang sometimes, and I want to kill it:

```
$ ./action.sh
^C
```

This works fine, no zombies left.

When I put this into background and try to terminate it, `nc` stays alive and I need to clean up manually:

```
& ./action.sh &
[1] 28747
& kill -15 28747 //here nc is still running! I have to find its PID and terminate it
```

Is there a way to ask `action.sh` to terminate `nc` too when it receives a termination signal?

Comment: `kill %n` where n if the number you see in the square brackets. AKA Job ID.  So  ` kill %1`   in this case

Comment: Is there any manual for this option? I could not find it on the sites used for mans like https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html

Comment: That's the man page for the kill command. You need to check the help for the kill shell built-in, see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

trap ctrl_c INT

function ctrl_c() {
    # redirect to stderr to avoid showing errors in case nc isn't found
    kill -9 $(pgrep nc) > /dev/null 2>&1
}

echo -n 'a' | nc a.b.c.d p
```

Comment: It would add much to your answer if you gave a brief explanation.

Comment: The `kill`+`pgrep` combo is better written with `pkill`. Also note that the name of the function is misleading as you don't send `SIGINT` to the process.

Answer (score 0):

This is also achievable by calling `kill` as below:

```
kill 15 -28747
```

*15* is the termination signal (use 9 for kill), and *28747* is the PID of the parent process in my question.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't flip those? I think it should be `kill -15 28747`...?